# How would I split a drawable bitmap image into its 3 RGB components in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bitmap

I want to create 3 images from one bitmap by setting each pixel to the red channel but I keep getting an error with ("java.lang.IllegalStateException") the code that I have now. [Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENJnz.jpg)
[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeAEj.png)

This is the result I'm looking for in these pictures. And then to do the same with the green and blue channels.

I've tried a few things but this is what I have currently:

```
    private Bitmap createRGB(Bitmap r) {

        //Red image
        for (int x = 0; x < r.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < r.getHeight(); y++)
            {
                r.setPixel(x, y, r.getPixel(x, y) & 0xFFFF0000);
            }
        }

        return r;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The original code works seem to be an issue with the scale of the image when going through the loop. The image size of 1200x1100 did not work however, 600x500 produced the correct result. (This is only for my machine, may work for bigger sizes on other android projects)

```
    private Bitmap createRGB(Bitmap r) {

        for(int i = 0; i < r.getWidth(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < r.getHeight(); j++){
                r.setPixel(i, j, r.getPixel(i, j) & 0xFFFF0000);
            }
        }

        return r;
    }
```

This works and changing the colour value will also produce Green and Blue results.

Comment: Try to increase your application heap size , or maybe process the bitmap after dividing into buffers... so it can process large resolution images too